# How do websites convert latex files to pdf?

Tags: javascript, php, html, pdf, pdf.js

Whenever a researcher submits his paper to a journal website he/she does so by uploading a latex file plus some figures in the format of eps, and after clicking on the submit button the files are converted to one pdf file. Does anyone know how they do that?

Is there a .js file that does that and is pdf.js capable of doing this?

Comment: `Does anyone know how they do that?` many ways, I'd suspect. `Is there a .js file that does that` a google search for `latex to pdf javascript` ... yielded much information - **first** link http://manuels.github.io/texlive.js - which does what you ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i imagine it's done server-side (after the files have been transmitted to the server) using typical latex-to-pdf workflow tools (e.g., the `pdflatex` command or similar). i imagine it's theoretically possible to write a javascript library to do it client-side in the browser <strike>though i haven't come across anything like that</strike>.

**Edit:** cool! as posted in Jaromanda X's comment above, there is in fact a JavaScript library for this. shows what i know. :p